# Error : Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:testCompile` in Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

Hi I am writing unit test cases of my demo android application,  so for this I am using `robolectric` unit framework. When I run it `gradlew test` then it gives error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:testCompile`. Please see attached screenshot.

Below is my root build.gradle

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

My project build.grade file looks like below

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xyz.robolectricapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        // this sets the root test folder to src/test overriding the default src/instrumentTest
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-test'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
    instrumentTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    instrumentTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}
```

Error Logs

[image]

Project Structure looks like below

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to grab the snapshot, you need to grab the 2.4-SNAPSHOT.

See: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/pom.xml

So replace     `testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'`
with     `testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4-SNAPSHOT'`

Or probably better to grab the stable 2.3 release: `org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3`

There is a sample gradle project here, it might be helpful: https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle